Python: Pandas, alternatives options for iterrow
I would know a more efficient way to iterate over rows on a pandas dataframe compared to iterrows.
I know that it exists the option of map but I can't find a good example.
Many examples are based on fixed columns for the csv and that you know the names of the columns.
But lets imagine a case that you recive many csv and each one has different numbers of columns.
I want my code to be the most generic possible.
I need to iterate over all rows and add each value (column of the row) to create a list for each row:
files = os.listdir(rute)

for file in list(files):
    filename = rute + '\\' + file
    print(filename)
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    df = df.fillna('') 
    columns = list(df.columns)
    
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        fila = []
        for key in columns:
            fila.append(row[key])
        print(fila)

This works, but I would like to find a most efficient way to do it.
Thanks

Are you looking for this: df.to_dict('tight')['data']

You can use apply like that :
list_of_row_values = df.apply(lambda row: row.tolist(), axis=1)

axis=1 makes it work column-wiseto manipulate each row directly.

I like this. If I want to cast all the values in the row (each column) with str() (a list a strings). How should I have to do it?

Something like this : df.apply(lambda row: [str(item) for item in row], axis=1)

Thank you!!! I will wait if there is another way more efficient like vector or something and then accept you answer.

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"/home/bera/Downloads/car_crashes.csv")
print(df.head())
#   total   speeding    alcohol not_distracted  no_previous ins_premium ins_losses  abbrev
# 0 18.8    7.332   5.64    18.048  15.04   784.55  145.08  AL
# 1 18.1    7.421   4.525   16.29   17.014  1053.48 133.93  AK

list_of_values = df.astype(str).values.tolist()
#print(list_of_values[:2])
# [['18.8', '7.332000000000001', '5.64', '18.048', '15.04','784.55','145.08','AL'],
#  ['18.1', '7.421', '4.525', '16.290000000000003','17.014','1053.48','133.93','AK']]


I don't know Pandas well, but I think the csv module will just give you your intended result without any fuss, and it's hard to beat csv.reader in terms of speed and memory (Pandas doesn't).
In one comment you state you'd like to do something that I interpreted as, "stringify the fields of every row":

Something like this : df.apply(lambda row: [str(item) for item in row], axis=1)

Do I interpret your goal correctly? If so, you're taking a very long, and memory expending, detour invoking Pandas which wants to parse-and-convert as much as it can just to throw all that work away. And, analogously, you're here asking if you can take that detour more quickly. Even if you can turn off the implicit conversions, Pandas will stay take longer and use more memory to do what csv.reader naturally does.
If you just want the textual values, the csv.reader yields each row as a list of strings (because, fundamentally, that's what a CSV file is... just text) without any parse-and-convert overhead:
import csv

files = ["input1.csv", "input2.csv"]

for fname in files:
    print(fname)
    with open(fname, newline="") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader)  # discard header, if you want to
        for row in reader:
            print("  ", row)

I have those two files in my working dir, and that prints:
input1.csv
   ['i']
   ['ii']
input2.csv
   ['1', 'a']
   ['2', 'b']

